# Attempt to write a readonly database - Django w/ SELinux error

Tags: django, sqlite, selinux

I have a CentOS server on which I have Apache, Django, Django CMS and mod_wsgi.  My Django project files are stored in the `/srv` directory and I have SELinux turned on for security reasons.

I've managed to successfully integrate Django-CMS into Django and when I visit the local IP, I see my pages.  However, when I try to visit /admin (where I can start making use of the CMS functionality), I get `DatabaseError at /admin/ attempt to write a readonly database`.

Okay.

So, since I have a `.sqlite` file in my project folder, I ran a `ls -l` on it which returned:

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 133120 Jan 5 11:53   DATABASE.sqlite
```

Okay, so I figured perhaps Apache couldn't read that file due to some permissions reasons so after a bunch of research on similar problems on Stackoverflow, I ran:

```
> chmod 664 DATABASE.sqlite
> chown apache /srv/mysite
> chown apache /srv/mysite/DATABASE.sqlite
```

Now, the `ls -l` output reads:

```
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache root 133120 Jan 5 11:53  DATABASE.sqlite
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same error when trying to access /admin on my Django app.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Probably something to do with SELinux permissions but I have no idea where to start in diagnosing what permissions issue is going on.

**EDIT:**

I ran

```
> chown apache:apache /srv/mysite
> chown apache:apache /srv/mysite/DATABASE.sqlite
```

and a quick `ls -l` reveals that the owner of the `mysite` directory and the `.sqlite` file is now `apache`.  However, I still get errors when trying to visit the `/admin` page.  I `chmod`ed the `/srv/mysite` directory to 757 and `DATABASE.sqlite` file to 756 because that's the best I can do to get the permissions to work out.  I was told that this is a security risk but I can't seem to figure out how to give it less permissions and get pass by `unable to read/open database file` errors.  Is it because of SELinux?

FYI, I'm operating under a regular user account in CentOS and sudo whenever I need to elevate:

```
[noblerare@localhost ]$
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You have to add writing rights to the directory in which your sqlite database is stored. So running `chmod -R u+w /srv/mysite/` should help.

If a server is using custom user (e.g. `www-data`) to access the database, the solution could be to change the owner of your database:

```
chown www-data:www-data /srv/mysite
chown www-data:www-data /srv/mysite/DATABASE.sqlite
```

Comment: I ended up doing 755 for `/srv/mysite` and 756 for `DATABASE.sqlite`.  Is this a security risk? If I change it to anything else, I error.

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  I ran `chown` using `apache` instead of `www-data` since I am on a CentOS system.  Anyway, now the owner of `/srv/mysite` and `DATABASE.sqlite` is `apache`.  But regardless of that, if I change the "everyone" permission to anything less than read/write/execute or read/write, I error.

Comment: hasn't worked for me unfortunately - still getting unable to open and cannot even cd to the database directory anymore bc of permissions :(

Comment: For me worked after `chmod -R u+w /srv/mysite/`

Answer (score 19):

In short, it happens when the application which writes to the sqlite database does not have write permission.

This can be solved in three ways:

1. **Granting ownership of `db.sqlite3` file  and its parent directory (thereby write access also) to the user using chown (Eg: `chown username db.sqlite3` )**
2. **Running the webserver (often gunicorn) as root user (run the command `sudo -i` before you run `gunicorn` or django `runserver`)**
3. **Allowing read and write access to all users by running command `chmod 777 db.sqlite3` (Dangerous option)**

Never go for the third option unless you are running the webserver in a local machine or the data in the database is not at all important for you.

Second option is also not recommended. But you can go for it, if you are sure that your application is not vulnerable for code injection attack.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is caused by SELinux.  After setting file ownership just as you did, I hit this issue.  The `audit2why(1)` tool can be used to diagnose SELinux denials from the log:

```
(django)[f22-4:www/django/demo] ftweedal% sudo audit2why -a
type=AVC msg=audit(1437490152.208:407): avc:  denied  { write }
      for  pid=20330 comm="httpd" name="db.sqlite3" dev="dm-1" ino=52036
      scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
      tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
      tclass=file permissive=0
    Was caused by:
    The boolean httpd_unified was set incorrectly. 
    Description:
    Allow httpd to unified

    Allow access by executing:
    # setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Sure enough, running `sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1` resolved the issue.

Looking into what `httpd_unified` is for, I came across a [fedora-selinux-list post](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-selinux-list/2009-March/msg00068.html) which explains:

> This Boolean is off by default, turning it on will allow all httpd
>   executables to have full access to all content labeled with a http file
>   context. Leaving it off makes sure that one httpd service can not
>   interfere with another.

So turning on `httpd_unified` lets you circumvent the default behaviour that prevents multiple `httpd` instances on the same server - all running as user `apache` - messing with each others' stuff.

In my case, I am only running one `httpd`, so it was fine for me to turn on `httpd_unified`.  If you cannot do this, I suppose some more fine-grained labelling is needed.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem but on Ubuntu Server.
So all I did is changed to superuser before I activate virtual environment for django and then I ran the django server.
It worked fine for me.

First copy paste

> `sudo su`

Then activate the virtual environment if you have one.

> `source myvenv/bin/activate`

At last run your django server.

> `python3 manage.py runserver`

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and I solved it by creating a directory in mysite folder to hold my db.sqlite3 file. so I did `/home/user/src/mysite/database/db.sqlite3`. In my django setting file I change my

```
 DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': "/home/user/src/mysite/database/db.sqlite3" ,
}}
```

I did this to make Django aware that I am storing my database in a sub directory of the base directory, which mysite in my case. Now you need to grant the permission to apache to be able read write the database.

```
chown user:www-data database/db.sqlite3
chown user:www-data database 
chmod 755 database
 chmod 755 database/db.sqlite3
```

This solved my problem. Here is a list of the different permissions. You can use choose the one that fits you
but avoid 777 and 666

-rw------- (600) -- Only the user has read and write permissions.

-rw-r--r-- (644) -- Only user has read and write permissions; the group and others can read only.

-rwx------ (700) -- Only the user has read, write and execute permissions.

-rwxr-xr-x (755) -- The user has read, write and execute permissions; the group and others can only read and execute.

-rwx--x--x (711) -- The user has read, write and execute permissions; the group and others can only execute.

-rw-rw-rw- (666) -- Everyone can read and write to the file. Bad idea.

-rwxrwxrwx (777) -- Everyone can read, write and execute. Another bad idea.

Here are a couple common settings for directories:

drwx------ (700) -- Only the user can read, write in this directory.

drwxr-xr-x (755) -- Everyone can read the directory, but its contents can only be changed by the user.

Here is a link to an article to learn more: [Fun with Numbers in chmod](http://ftp.kh.edu.tw/Linux/Redhat/en_6.2/doc/gsg/s1-navigating-chmodnum.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it.

```
sudo chmod 774 . || sudo chmod 776 .
```

Pay particular attention to the *.* because most of the time the reason why this doesnt work is because we try this:

```
sudo chmod 774 db.sqlite3
```

But what your trying to do is open access to the folder that contains: db.sqlite3 not the database itself. If this doesn't solve it completely then try this:

```
sudo chmod 774 db.sqlite3
```

Then it should work. Cheers!

Comment: The bottom two commands are the same, I believe there was a typo in the last command.

Comment: for django on aws ubuntu you may face this error and this is exact solution but use 774 or 777 wisely

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. To check if SELinux is the problem, one can check its running status with

```
sestatus
```

and temporarily disable it with

```
setenforce 0
```

This could at least help to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change **acl**s without touching the ownership and permissions of file/directory.

Use the following commands:

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:rwx /home/user/website
setfacl -m u:www-data:rw /home/user/website/db.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the owner of your database file and it's folder to `django`:

```
chown django:django /home/django/mysite
chown django:django /home/django/mysite/my_db.sqlite3
```

This work for DigitalOcean's 1-Click Django Droplet

Answer (score -12):

Here my solution:

```
root@fiq:/home/django/django_project# chmod 777 db.sqlite3
root@fiq:/home/django/django_project# cd ..
root@fiq:/home/django# chmod 777 *
```

Go to `<'your_website/admin'>` put username and password.. That's it.

Comment: Highly unsafe, you are setting 777 to the DB, since SQLite's database is self-contained in the file it is literally giving 777 to any user on your server.

Comment: That's a really bad idea.

Comment: This answer is a joke. No one should ever do this.