# SQLite error attempt to write to a read-only database

Tags: django, apache, sqlite, mod-wsgi

I've been struggling to deploy my django project with Apache and mod_wsgi. I've had many problems that I managed to handle, but this one just seems not to be solvable.

I get the following error in my apache log when I enter the address setakshop.ir:8080 :

```
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error] Internal Server Error: /en-gb/
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 87, in get_response
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oscar/apps/basket/middleware.py", line 26, in process_request
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     strategy = selector.strategy(request=request, user=request.user)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oscar/apps/partner/strategy.py", line 39, in strategy
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     return Default(request)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oscar/apps/partner/strategy.py", line 57, in __init__
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     if request and request.user.is_authenticated():
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 224, in inner
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     self._setup()
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 357, in _setup
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 22, in <lambda>
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 10, in get_user
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 152, in get_user
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 49, in __getitem__
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     return self._session[key]
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 175, in _get_session
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     self._session_cache = self.load()
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 29, in load
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     self.create()
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 41, in create
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     self.save(must_create=True)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 64, in save
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     obj.save(force_insert=must_create, using=using)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 589, in save
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 698, in _save_table
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 731, in _do_insert
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     using=using, raw=raw)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 921, in execute_sql
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error]     return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
[Wed May 27 05:54:24 2015] [error] OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

Now I googled this error and searched a lot, I mean a lot! I know that the db.sqlite file must have write permissions and it should be owned by apache ( www-data ), also the directory containing it must have write permissions and be owned by www-data. and I have done these two things. I don't have selinux installed, I've ran ./manage.py migrate, and I don't know what else I can do to make this work, I even chmoded both the directory and the db.sqlite file to 777 to just see if it will work, but it didn't and I know that's not a safe thing to do.

now for your information this is the folder containing the db.sqlite file:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan      382 Jan 30 11:54 README.rst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan        0 Jan 30 11:54 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x 4 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Feb  6 15:15 apps
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 741376 May 27 09:11 db.sqlite
drwxrwxr-x 7 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Jan 30 11:54 deploy
drwxrwxr-x 2 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Jan 30 11:54 fixtures
drwxrwxr-x 2 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Feb 22 00:14 i18n
drwxrwxr-x 3 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Feb 23 21:45 locale
drwxr-xr-x 2 ashkan   ashkan     4096 May 26 08:33 logs
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ashkan   ashkan      242 May 26 00:22 manage.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ashkan   ashkan       10 May 25 23:15 oscar -> i18n/oscar
drwxrwxr-x 4 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Jan 30 21:53 public
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan    14306 May 26 00:07 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan    10230 May 26 00:23 settings.pyc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan    14876 Feb  6 14:26 settings.py~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan      293 Jan 30 11:54 settings_mysql.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan      266 May 26 00:16 settings_postgres.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan      162 Jan 30 11:54 settings_sphinx.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Feb 23 21:45 static
drwxrwxr-x 3 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Jan 30 11:54 templates
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ashkan   ashkan     1114 Jan 30 11:54 test_migrations.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ashkan   ashkan     1138 Jan 30 11:54 update_latest.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan     1573 Jan 30 11:54 urls.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan     1427 Jan 30 21:53 urls.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 2 ashkan   ashkan     4096 Jan 30 20:58 whoosh_index
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashkan   ashkan      778 May 26 00:23 wsgi.py
```

and this is the directory containing the db.sqlite file:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 ashkan   ashkan       866 Jan 30 11:54 README.rst
drwxrwxr-x  2 ashkan   ashkan      4096 Jan 30 11:54 _fixtures
-rw-rw-r--  1 ashkan   ashkan    897149 Feb  6 15:34 alaki
-rw-rw-r--  1 ashkan   ashkan   1818857 Feb  6 15:37 alaki.txt
drwxrwxr-x  9 ashkan   ashkan      4096 Jan 30 11:54 demo
-rw-rw-r--  1 ashkan   ashkan    443627 Feb  6 15:34 out
drwxrwxrwx 12 www-data www-data    4096 May 27 09:11 sandbox
drwxrwxr-x  5 ashkan   ashkan      4096 Jan 30 11:54 us
```

any idea what's causing this problem? thank you.

**update 1 :**

here is my apache config :

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    WSGIDaemonProcess setak python-path=/home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
    WSGIProcessGroup setak 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/wsgi.py 
    ServerAdmin admin@setakshop.ir 
    ServerName setakshop.ir:8000 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ 

    Alias /media/ /home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/media/ 
    Alias /static/ /home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/static/ 

    <Directory /home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Files>    
    </Directory>    

    <Directory /home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/static>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/media>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>    

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel info

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**update 2 :**

here is my wsgi.py :

```
import os
import sys
import site
import urllib

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

# Project root
root = '/home/ashkan/django-oscar/sites/sandbox'
sys.path.insert(0, root)

# Packages from virtualenv
activate_this = '/home/ashkan/django-oscar/oscar/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

# Set environmental variable for Django and fire WSGI handler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
_application = get_wsgi_application()

def application(environ, start_response):
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = urllib.unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')[0])
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

Comment: What is the NAME value in the DATABASES setting in the Django settings file set to? If you add to the Django settings file ``print __file__``, what is output in the Apache error log indicating where the Django settings file is located.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the NAME value is : '/home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/db.sqlite' , and it was : location('db.sqlite') before i changed it. as for print __file__ , nothing is added to the error log

Comment: Check the main Apache error log and not just the VirtualHost log if you have one. The value must be logged unless you have a really wrong setting for LogLevel in Apache. If it isn't logged it would suggest that settings file isn't even being used, which could well mean it is picking up different value to what you expect from somewhere else. You could also add a syntax error to the settings file to see if it fails to be loaded.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i added a syntax error and nothing appeared in the log file again! I removed the settings.pyc and settings.py~ file too. I will add my apache config now to the post.

Comment: And what is in your wsgi.py file? If you add print() statements for debugging in the wsgi.py file are they output to the Apache error log?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i also added the wsgi file to the post. i added the print __file__ line in wsgi.py, and still nothing in the apache log. should I use something other than print __file__ ??

Comment: Is there anything in the 'error.log' file matching that application? Because you have LogLevel set to info, then mod_wsgi should at least log when the WSGI script file is loaded. You can also remove ``sys.stdout = sys.stderr`` line as it is not needed.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yes there is, the wsgi prints out the request details everytime the site is visited. something like : Request repr():
[Wed May 27 08:38:41 2015] [error] <WSGIRequest
[Wed May 27 08:38:41 2015] [error] path:/,
[Wed May 27 08:38:41 2015] [error] GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
[Wed May 27 08:38:41 2015] [error] POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
 and the rest.
and I just noticed that the print __file__ prints out the file path in the apache log.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton also on apache restart : 
[[Wed May 27 13:21:00 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12137): Create interpreter 'setakshop.ir:8080|'.
[Wed May 27 13:21:00 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12137): Adding '/home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox' to path.
[Wed May 27 13:21:00 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=12137): Adding '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Wed May 27 13:21:00 2015] [info] [client 2.190.1.87] mod_wsgi (pid=12137, process='setak', application='setakshop.ir:8080|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/wsgi.py'.

Comment: Why is there '/home/ashkan/freshcopy/django-oscar' and '/home/ashkan/django-oscar'? The fact that the latter is set in the wsgi.py file would be overriding where your project is being picked up from and possibly screwing up some things.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thank you Mr dumpleton, this solved the problem. wsgi.py was set from a previous setup and I forgot to change that part. thanks a million times. if you post this, I'll accept it as an answer